# Why ajax returns the latest variable of a loop in html template?

Tags: html, jquery, django, ajax

I have a html file as bellow:

```
<div  id="preview_updated_notifications">
      {% for lst in unread_list %}

         <div >
           <span data-notification-item="{{ lst.id }}" id="_mark_as_read_id"> ●</span>                             
         </div>
      {% endfor %}
</div>
```

and in js file:

```
$(document).on('click', "#_mark_as_read_id", function() {
    var object_id =  $('#_mark_as_read_id').data('notification-item');

    console.log('--------------object_id:------------')
    console.log(object_id)
    console.log('--------------------------')

    $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "{% url '_mark_as_read' object_id %}",
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: {
                        'object_id': object_id,
                  },

                  dataType: 'json',
                  success: function (data) {
                      $('#preview_updated_notifications').html('**TEST**');

                  }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
    });
```

But the problem is that this always prints the latest value of loop, while I expect after clicking on each item `●` retrieve the relative id!

Comment: you have to add javascript code also in the for loop and add {{ lst.id }} to your html id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the issue of the non-unique IDs you can delegate like this instead

```
$("#preview_updated_notifications").on("click","[data-notification-item]",function() {
  const id = $(this).data("notification-item");
  ....
})
```

Comment: I like your solution, but I don't know why it does not perform the ajax part?!

Comment: @J2015 What do you mean? My code is just a snippet

Answer (score 1):

`{% url '_mark_as_read' object_id %}` is a Django template tag, meaning that it gets rendered when the page first loads, so the value of `object_id` will always be the one initially passed as context, from the view.

You could use another HTML attribute, to store the update URL for each `span`, which would allow you to use the Django `{% url ... %}` tag.

Furthermore, as you have `id="_mark_as_read_id"` inside a for loop, every `<span>` element will have the same ID. IDs should be unique. You should use a class instead, and update the selector in the click function accordingly.

HTML:

```
<span data-notification-item="{{ lst.id }}" class="mark-as-read" data-update-link="{% url '_mark_as_read' lst.id %}"> ●</span>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', ".mark-as-read", function() {
```

Then in your jQuery you could access it like this:

```
var update_url =  $(this).data('update-link');
```

Answer (score 1):

in

```
      {% for lst in unread_list %}

         <div >
           <span data-notification-item="{{ lst.id }}" id="_mark_as_read_id"> ●</span>                             
         </div>
      {% endfor %}
```

many spans are rendered, and each of them has the same `id`. `id` should be unique in HTML, that is why only one span response to you.

Answer (score 1):

You are using django `for loop` for html only, the javascript code also needs to be in your `for loop` like this:

```
<div  id="preview_updated_notifications">
{% for 1st in unread_list %}

<div >
    <span data-notification-item="{{ lst.id }}" id="_mark_as_read_id{{ lst.id }}"> ●</span>                             
</div>
<script> 
$(document).on('click', "#_mark_as_read_id{{ lst.id }}", function() {
    var object_id =  $('#_mark_as_read_id{{ lst.id }}').data('notification-item');

    console.log('--------------object_id:------------')
    console.log(object_id)
    console.log('--------------------------')

    $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "{% url '_mark_as_read' object_id %}",
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: {
                        'object_id': object_id,
                  },

                  dataType: 'json',
                  success: function (data) {
                      $('#preview_updated_notifications').html('**TEST**');

                  }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

- For every span html id, added `{{ lst.id }}`. So the id's will be like (`_mark_as_read_id1`, `_mark_as_read_id2`, `_mark_as_read_id3`, ....).

Now, it will get after clicking on each item `●` retrieve the relative id!